# Top menu on success sage

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml

I've been testin with Magento 1.9.3.9, Ultimo theme and Firecheckout extension.

I've noticed that there are no top menu on success page like on all other pages. I've tried to add the top menu block via local.xml:

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="top.menu">
        <action method="insert">
            <block>catalog.topnav.menu</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

But got this error message:

```
Mage registry key "umm_top_menu_exists" already exists

#0 /var/www/html/mage/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /var/www/html/mage/app/design/frontend/ultimo/websiteone/template/infortis/ultramegamenu/mainmenu.phtml(56): Mage::register('umm_top_menu_ex...', true)
#2 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/html/p...')
#3 /var/www/html/mage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
...
```

I understand that this means the block is still initializied and can't be loaded twice but for my understanding medtho insert won't initialize it again but load the existing block. Thats why I wonder why I got this message.

Looks like I miss something but I don't know what.

Comment: Can you check if the top is hidden by display none somewhere in your code for success page? Also check by disabling the firecheckout if its showing perfectly or not.

Comment: The template files are not loaded. I've enabled template hints and double checked it by searching for "nav container" in source code. I#ve noticed something odd, the installation is a multistore installation. Two of the stores using the ultimo theme one have this issue, the other not. I've compared the local.xml filesof both shops to determine if there might be any differences between them, but there are only minor differences related to each shop individual presence. I've checked the ultimo manual if there is an option to disable the top menu on checkout but didn't find an option like that.